# is it possible to know how the activity start?

Tags: android, android-activity, alarmmanager

is it possible to know which one started the activity? user or alarmmanager?
i want to know how the activiy started. By alarmmanager or by user?

Comment: can you explain more? A little vague...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're managing the alarms yourself then you should be able to store a special flag in the intent using `putExtra`.

**Edit** -
In fact, all of the `AlarmManager` set methods require a `PendingIntent`, which is essentially an `Intent` wrapped in some other data. You have full control over how this `PendingIntent` is created, so the world is your oyster!

Answer (score 2):

You can access Intent object, which started your activity and get information from it, via getAction() for instance, or using Extras.

Comment: thanks for the answers. however my activity is called directly, not by an intent. so how can i determine how it is called? is it same?

Comment: i used putextra and getintent().getextras(). now it works perfect. thanks all.